# derived classes, parameters and performace

Tags: c#

Lets say I got this set up:

```
class MainInfo
{
    public string path{get;set;}
    public string name{get;set;}
}

class MoreInfo : MainInfo
{
    // more variables and methods
}
```

And inside another class I got MoreInfo class declared as `public MoreInfo info;`

In some other method I only need `MainInfo` information, now what I want to know is will there be any performace diffrence if I pass to some other method `info` casted as  `MainInfo` like so:  `(MainInfo)info` as a parameter insted of just passing in whole `info` and then in the method getting out only the information I need?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Or if I pass a parameter like so `MainInfo in = (MainInfo)info;`. Is there any diffrence between these three?

Comment: 1. You are worrying too much. 2. You should read a book about object-oriented programming.

Comment: You've written the code both ways. You want to know which one is faster. Run them both and you'll know! That's the only way to find out, so what are you waiting for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, if you are passing a MoreInfo object to a method that is expecting an MainInfo object, you do NOT need to cast, and you should not do so.

Secondly, it will only be passing a pointer either way so it will run at the same speed.
The only overhead is where it adjusts a pointer by the size of the extra data in the derived class; obviously that's not really a measureable difference in speed.

Comment: You: _it adjusts a pointer by the size of the extra data in the derived class_ No, that doesn't sound like the way a reference conversion works. The _run-time_ type of the object instance will still be `MoreInfo` even if some _references_ of type `MainInfo` exist that point to the instance.

Comment: Here's an [interesting article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8052/Type-casting-impact-over-execution-performance-in) on this.

Comment: @Jeppe: You're right - for upcasting in C#, it doesn't need to adjust anything. I was thinking of how C++ does it, but C# is of course not like C++ where you can have multiple base classes (which is where the compiler *does* have to adjust the 'this' pointer sometimes). In C#, you can only ever have one base class, so that issue doesn't arise.

Comment: @MatthewWatson In C#, a class can implement multiple interfaces, so the issue *does* arise. But it's not solved by adjusting the pointer, as it's usually done in C++ implementations.

Comment: @svick Nah, I don't know about other runtimes or environments, but the way .NET does it if you say e.g. `ICloneable x = "Hello";` or `IConvertible y = "Hello";` does not feel like "adjusting a pointer by the size of the extra data". The object keeps its identity as a `System.String`, but the _reference_ can be an `ICloneable` or an `IConvertible` because `String` implements those interfaces. But nobody knows what data an `ICloneable` possesses, hence nobody knows which of `Strings`'s data are "extra". An interface cannot have any fields, only signatures for methods, properties, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If the method takes a `MainInfo`, you don't need to cast any inheriting types - just pass it directly.

As for performance - this is not something you are ever likely to have an issue with. This would a micro-micro optimization and there will be far larger possible optimizations in just about any piece of software.

Answer (score 1):

Casts have some performance cost, but you know: premature optimization is the devil of any development.

Make your design decisions and later care about optimization. If your method needs a more concrete `MoreInfo` instance because it needs to access the whole info, maybe it's a good choice to just give the downcasted object to `MoreInfo`. If not, just leave the object *as is* with the `MainInfo` typing.

Comment: Actually, in his example the cast is unneccessary so I imagine the compiler will ignore it.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I was talking in general terms. Check my answer: I said that if OP needs the info within the more concrete type, ok, if not, go with the less concrete `MainInfo`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a performance difference with casting, but I don't think it's big enough to matter.  Did a test with your class above and got a result of 2218 ticks without casting and 135 ticks with casting.  I believe it's because it handles the cast during compile time.  Hope this helps!

```
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
watch.Start();
testmethod(info);
watch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedTicks);  // 2218 ticks

watch.Restart();
testmethod((MainInfo)info);
watch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedTicks); // 135 ticks
```